# Can someone explain me why "curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 2000: Connection refused"?

Tags: go, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I do not understand why it says "curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 2000: Connection refused" :

```
curl -X POST -F 'first_name=pinco' -F 'last_name=pallo' -F 'company_name=Company' -F 
'email=pinco.pallo@company.com' -F 'tel=111111111' 127.0.0.1:2000/puser/add curl: (7) Failed
to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 2000: Connection refused.
```

In server-gorillamux.go :

```
CONN_PORT = "2000"
```

in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf :

```
upstream golang-webserver {
    ip_hash;
    server 127.0.0.1:2000;
}

server {
    #listen 2999;
    server_name ggc.world;

    root /puser/add; // Is this correct?

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+CHACHA20-draft:EECDH+AES128:RSA+AES128:EECDH+AES256:RSA+AES256:EECDH+3DES:RSA+3DES:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;

    location / {
        #proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_pass http://golang-webserver;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        #proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

This is the ggc/goServer/server-gorillamux.go :

```
package main

import (
        "encoding/json"
        "github.com/gorilla/mux"
        "log"
        "net/http"
)

const (
        CONN_HOST = "192.168.1.7"
        CONN_PORT = "2000"
)

type Puser struct {
        first_name   string `json:"first_name"`
        last_name    string `json:"last_name"`
        country      string `json:"country"`
        company_name string `json:"company_name"`
        email        string `json:"email"`
        tel          string `json:"tel"`
}

type Pusers []Puser
var pusers []Puser

type Route struct {
        Name        string
        Method      string
        Pattern     string
        HandlerFunc http.HandlerFunc
}

type Routes []Route

var routes = Routes{
        Route{
                "getPusers",
                "GET",
                "/pusers",
                getPusers,
        },
        Route{
                "addPuser",
                "POST",
                "/puser/add",
                addPuser,
        },
}


func getPusers(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(pusers)
}

func addPuser(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        puser := Puser{}
        err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&puser)
        if err != nil {
                log.Print("error occured while decoding puser data 
:: ", err)
        }
        log.Printf("adding puser id :: % s with firstName ass :: %s 
and lastName as :: %s ", puser.first_name, puser.last_name)
        pusers = append(pusers, Puser{first_name: puser.first_name,
            last_name: puser.last_name, country: puser.country, 
company_name: puser.company_name,
                email: puser.email, tel: puser.tel})
        json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(pusers)
}

func AddRoutes(router *mux.Router) *mux.Router {
        for _, route := range routes {
                router.
                        Methods(route.Method).
                        Path(route.Pattern).
                        Name(route.Name).
                        Handler(route.HandlerFunc)
        }
        return router
}

func main() {
        muxRouter := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
        router := AddRoutes(muxRouter)
        router.PathPrefix("/").Handler(http.FileServer(http.Dir("..
/src/components/auth/Forms.vue"))) 

        err := http.ListenAndServe(CONN_HOST+":"+CONN_PORT, router)
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal("error starting http server :: ", err)
                return
        }
}
```

This is the complete /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf :

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    server_name ggc.world;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/ggc.world-
0002/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/ggc.world-   
0002/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/ggc.world
/chain.pem;

    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by 
Certbot

    ssl_session_timeout 5m;
    #ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+CHACHA20-
draft:EECDH+AES128:RSA+AES128:EECDH+AES256:RSA+AES256:EECDH+3DES:RSA+3DE
S:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
    #ssl_stapling on;
    #ssl_stapling_verify on;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/ggcworld-access.log combined;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        #proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        #proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

    location /weights {
      #sendfile on;
      #tcp_nopush on;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /home/marco/webMatters/vueMatters
/ggc/src/components/auth/weights/;
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9091/weights/;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      # Following is necessary for Websocket support
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }

}

server {
    if ($host = ggc.world) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    error_page 497 https://$host:$server_port$request_uri;
    server_name ggc.world;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/ggcworld-access.log combined;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        #proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        #proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}

upstream websocket {
    ip_hash;
    server localhost:3000;
}

server {
    listen 81;
    server_name ggc.world;

    location ~ ^/(websocket|websocket\/socket-io) {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4201;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header X-Forwared-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;

        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
}

upstream golang-webserver {
    ip_hash;
    server 127.0.0.1:2000;
}

server {
    #listen 2999;
    server_name ggc.world;

    root /puser/add;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+CHACHA20-
  draft:EECDH+AES128:RSA+AES128:EECDH+AES256:RSA+AES256:EECDH+3DES:RSA+3DE
S:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://golang-webserver;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        #proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

The port 2000 is already opened for TCP and UDP in the Internet Service Provider configuration.

Update 1)

after putting in server-gorillamux.go CONN_HOST = "127.0.0.1" the type of error has changed:

```
curl -X POST -F 'first_name=pinco' -F 'last_name=pallo' -F   
'company_name=Company'  -F 'email=pinco.pallo@company.com' -F  
'tel=111111111' http://127.0.0.1:2000/puser/add
[{}]


go run ./server-gorillamux.go
2020/05/13 12:24:55 error occured while decoding puser data :: invalid
character '-' in numeric literal
2020/05/13 12:24:55 adding puser id ::  with firstName ass ::  and 
lastName as :: %!s(MISSING)
```

Update 2)

```
curl --verbose -X POST -d'{"first_name":"pinco", "last_name":"pallo", 
"company_name":"Company","email":"pinco.pallo@company.com","tel":"11111111
1"}' 127.0.0.1:2000/puser/add
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 2000 (#0)
> POST /puser/add HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:2000
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 121
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
* upload completely sent off: 121 out of 121 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Wed, 13 May 2020 11:01:00 GMT
< Content-Length: 8
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< 
[{},{}]
* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact

go run ./server-gorillamux.go
2020/05/13 13:01:00 adding puser id ::  with firstName ass ::  and 
lastName as :: %!s(MISSING)
```

Update 3:

Capitalizing the first letter of each field make the json see them, but the values of each field are not yet exported. 
There must be something to fix in addPuser function :

```
curl -X POST -F 'first_name=pinco' -F 'last_name=pallo' -F 
'company_name=Company'  -F 'email=pinco.pallo@company.com' -F  
'tel=111111111' http://127.0.0.1:2000/puser/add
    [{"First_name":"","Last_name":"","Country":"","Company_name":"","Email":""
,"Tel":""}]  o run ./server-gorillamux.go
2020/05/13 13:27:03 error occured while decoding puser data :: invalid
character '-' in numeric literal
2020/05/13 13:27:03 adding puser id ::  with firstName as :: , 
lastName as :: , country as :: $s,companyName as :: , email as :: , 
tel as::
```

Looking forward to your kind help.
Marco

Comment: Can you show , how you configure your server?

Comment: @GrigoriyMikhalkin I put in my post the complete go web-server and the complete nginx web-server

Comment: You set `CONN_HOST = "192.168.1.7"` -- probably that's the problem

Comment: @GrigoriyMikhalkin after putting CONN_HOST = "127.0.0.1"  , url -X POST -F 'first_name=pinco' -F 'last_name=pallo' -F 'company_name=Company'  -F 'email=pinco.pallo@company.com' -F 'tel=111111111' http://127.0.0.1:2000/puser/add
[{}]
go run ./server-gorillamux.go 
2020/05/13 12:24:55 error occured while decoding puser data :: invalid character '-' in numeric literal
2020/05/13 12:24:55 adding puser id ::  with firstName ass ::  and lastName as :: %!s(MISSING)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Purser` fields are unexported, so JSON decoder doesn't see them, you need to capitalize them to fix that:

```
type Puser struct {
        FirstName    string `json:"first_name"`
        LastName     string `json:"last_name"`
        Country      string `json:"country"`
        CompanyName  string `json:"company_name"`
        Email        string `json:"email"`
        Tel          string `json:"tel"`
}
```

Then, also you make wrong request, sending parameters in form data, instead send JSON object in request body, like this:

```
curl -X POST -d'{"first_name":"pinco", "last_name":"pallo", "company_name":"Company","email":"pinco.pallo@company.com","tel":"111111111"}' 127.0.0.1:2000/puser/add
```

Comment: there must be something else also to fix :  curl -X POST -d'{"first_name":"pinco", "last_name":"pallo", "company_name":"Company","email":"pinco.pallo@company.com","tel":"111111111"}' 127.0.0.1:2000/puser/add
[{}]go run ./server-gorillamux.go
2020/05/13 12:54:55 adding puser id ::  with firstName ass ::  and lastName as :: %!s(MISSING)

Comment: As i said, there is bugs in you logging message: fix it to `adding puser with firstName ass :: %s 
and lastName as :: %s`. You're logging only two fields.

Comment: Updated answer, didn't noticed that `Purser` fields are unexported.

Comment: capitalizing the first letter of each field make the json see them, but the values of each field are not yet exported. There must be something to fix in addPuser function :  curl -X POST -F 'first_name=pinco' -F 'last_name=pallo' -F 'company_name=Company'  -F 'email=pinco.pallo@company.com' -F 'tel=111111111' http://127.0.0.1:2000/puser/add
[{"First_name":"","Last_name":"","Country":"","Company_name":"","Email":"","Tel":""}]

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/-bbAA2Fg1Hb -- this version works for me. And as i stated before, you need to send JSOn on request body

Comment: Mikhalking I corrected curl usage: curl -d'{"first_name":"pinco", "last_name":"pallo", "company_name":"Company","email":"pinco.pallo@company.com","tel":"111111111"}' \
> -H "Content-Type: application/json" 127.0.0.1:2000/puser/add
[{"First_name":"pinco","Last_name":"pallo","Country":"","Company_name":"Company","Email":"pinco.pallo@company.com","Tel":"111111111"}]
server-gorillamux.go 
2020/05/13 14:40:33 adding puser id :: pinco with firstName as :: pallo, lastName as :: , country as :: $s,companyName as :: Company, email as :: pinco.pallo@company.com, tel as:: 111111111